# GeoLocation using Phonegap and Android

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, jquery-mobile, geolocation

I am Designing a mobile app on phonegap. In this I am trying to get curent location of user. But I am not getting the map on Andriod Emulator.
I used this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

     <head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height; user-scalable=no" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>PhoneGap Map</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function onLoad() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError,{alert("error"),"enableHighAccuracy":true,"timeout":3000});

}

//GEOLOCATION
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    alert("Latitude: "  + position.coords.latitude   + "\n" +
          "Longitude:" + position.coords.longitude  + "\n");

    var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
    var myLong = position.coords.longitude;

    //MAP
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                  mapOptions);

};

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert("code: "    + error.code    + "\n" +
          "message: " + error.message + "\n");
}


     </script>

     </head>
     <body onload="onLoad()"> 
     <div>map</div>
     <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100px; height: 100px;" ></div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

I don't know where I am gng wrong.Can any one please help me on this?

Comment: Is your code executing? Do you get any alert, either the success or the error one?

Comment: No David, I getting only blank page

Comment: Try putting `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError,{alert("error"),"enableHighAccuracy":true,"timeout":3000});` within the `onLoad` function

Comment: Davids- I tried ,But same result. I have one doubt, When I am running in PC browser I am getting the Geolocation.whats the problem with AVD>

Comment: Did you whitelist the maps.googleapis.com domain?

Comment: Simon- Yeah, I did it.same result. Will it require device to test geolocation or should we get in emulator

Answer (score 0):

Check this code... change cordova-1.8.1.js into ur cordova2.0.js... remaining source is refer thro online. If its not works. then there problem in ur phonegap configuration.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Info Window Simple</title>
                <link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
                    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
                     <script type="text/javascript" charset ="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
                    <script>
                        function initialize() {
                            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
                            var mapOptions = {
                                zoom: 4,
                                center: myLatlng,
                                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                            }

                            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

                            var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                            '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
                            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                            '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
                            'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
                            'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
                            'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
                            '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
                            'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
                            'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
                            'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
                            'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
                            'Heritage Site.</p>'+
                            '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
                            'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
                            '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '</div>';

                            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                                                        content: contentString
                                                                        });

                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                                position: myLatlng,
                                                                map: map,
                                                                title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
                                                                });
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                                                          infowindow.open(map,marker);
                                                          });
                        }

                        </script>
                    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Im not working in ur code. because its not clear whether you properly set up environment for phonegap. So try this. If its not working. then u go through entire setup once again.

Comment: RED.Skull- Thanks, But this is for getting map by providing latlng statically. I got it. But I am trying for current user location ,that I am not getting it On AVD.

Comment: Can u provide ur logcat error message and another thing is try it on Device also